# iOS dev center certificates, identifiers & profiles gets stuck in loading screen

Tags: ios, udid

I have this very frustrating issue with iOS dev center. Every time I want to add a new iOS-device by its UDID the site gets stuck in the loading screen. This same problem occurs when I want to change an existing distribution profile. The site just goes "Loading" forever.

Considering that this occurs on all my devices (computers, mobilephones etc.) I would be very grateful if someone had any idea how to deal with this problem..

Comment: Still happening in 2015. Unfortunately Apple's whole development chain is a steaming pile.

Comment: Same error on Safari logged in on normal and parallel private browsing on different accounts.

Comment: I actually had this issue with Safari. Weirdly, I could only solve it by using Firefox instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you using Safari? For some reason the dev site doesn't always play nice with other browsers like Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Safari worked better, but I recall having the same problem with Safari also, thanks!

Comment: Cannot believe such things still happens in apple's website.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for some time now. Actually even it is get stuck the device is added to  my list. So just refresh the page after a while to see if it is added.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm doing and it feels dirty!

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of research into what the underlying issue was with this on Chrome.  Seems there are multiple parts to this issue.

Firstly clearing cookies seem to help (partly) it got me past one hanging loading screen (first step of adding a new device), however I was still hanging on the next step.

Further investigation with Chrome developer tools indicated that Chrome was refusing to load some content due to XHR restrictions.  Seems that Apple mixes https and http content. I was able to get past that by click on the shield icon on the right on the address bar and telling Chrome to allow the mixed content.

Finally there was also an issue with X-FRAME-OPTIONS headers that are being sent in the response which generate the following errors

```
Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN, DENY') encountered when loading 'https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceComplete.action?returnURL='. Falling back to 'DENY'.

Refused to display 'https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceComplete.action?returnURL=' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN, DENY'.
```

There are a couple of extensions available to remove X-FRAME-OPTION headers, but I wasn't able to get those working and wouldn't really recommend it.

My guess is that this works ok on Safari as it's not as strict on the XHR and X-FRAME-OPTION rules.

Anyway hope that helps someone. I'm going to raise a support request with Apple to see if they can get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with Chrome and Safari on OS X but it works fine with Chrome on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the cookies in chrome settings.This has always helped me.